# Excel: find value from column in text string and return it

Tags: excel

I have two sheets  - one contains column with list of events: lets say Event!A2:A20  bla1 blabla2 bla3 ....

and second sheet with cell containing  long text with sometimes has events listed in Event! and sometimes not : fx textTextBla1Texttext

What I need is to check if any of words from Events! table is present in text string from cell and if yes to print it. If not then lets say "other"

Original Event table looks like :

```
Event type                                      Event Count
BACK-UP PATH STATUS CHANG                       1419
SOFTWARE ERROR - COMMUNICATIONS PROGRAM LINE    273
CONNECTION FAILURE - DISK RESOURCE NAME         59
COMMUNICATION PROTOCOL ERROR -  SENSE DATA      61
EtherChannel Recovery                           23
```

Event count uses formula :

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Eventy!A2;SN_Data!$J$2:$J$6224)))
```

to count number or Event Type in second sheet from Column J containing text string such as:

```
ITM6 K20 EventReceived:ERRPT:ERRPT:Event Msg:hdisk83: BACK-UP PATH STATUS CHANGE
```

What I'd like to achieve is get column lets say K filled up witch Event Type if it matches string in Column J like :

```
J                                                                K
Full descritpion                                                 Event Type
Msg:hdisk83: BACK-UP PATH STATUS CHANGE - DISK RESOURCE NAME.    BACK-UP PATH STATUS
```

If no match found then just print Other

Comment: So, your Column A2:A20 has unique strings? Or is A2:A20 one string? Can you post a sample table of what you mean? What have you tried so far?  I'm sort of confused, is "Event" a worksheet?

Comment: Event type                                                                             Event Count
BACK-UP PATH STATUS CHANG                                                1419
SOFTWARE ERROR - COMMUNICATIONS PROGRAM LINE 273
CONNECTION FAILURE - DISK RESOURCE NAME                 59
COMMUNICATION PROTOCOL ERROR -  SENSE DATA         61
etc
it uses formula =SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Eventy!A2;SN_Data!$J$2:$J$6224)))   to count reoccurence  and the string in with we search for Event type looks : :Event Msg:hdisk57: BACK-UP PATH STATUS CHANGE - DISK RESOURCE NAME.

Comment: Can you edit that into the original post? It'd be easier to read and you can use code tags.